# How to align widget to another widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface

This is the UI that I aim to achieve

[image]

Hi everyone, I'm new to Flutter and i have a problem, How can I create a UI like the one in the image, consisting of two images connected by an arrow?
I've used the `Positioned` widget, but I'm unsure how to correctly position the arrow to match the design. Could someone help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following:

- Use a `Row` to position your cards.
- Rotate your cards using `Transform.rotate`.
- Use a `Stack` and put the `Row` and the `Image` inside that.

Result:

[image]

Code:

```dart
class MySampleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MySampleWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const arrowSize = 50.0;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Center(child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
          final width = constraints.maxWidth * 0.4;
          return Stack(
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Transform.rotate(
                    angle: pi / 20,
                    child: Container(
                      width: width,
                      height: width,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Transform.rotate(
                    angle: pi / 20,
                    child: Container(
                      width: width,
                      height: width,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: constraints.maxWidth / 2 - arrowSize / 2,
                top: -arrowSize / 2,
                child: Image.network(
                  'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/e1/dd/4a/e1dd4a304f0ad506a4dde90bf6d393f0.jpg',
                  width: arrowSize,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        })),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Just use a better image for the arrow (transparent background).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this by using rows and columns or you can use stack widget as well.

Here's a solution using rows and columns:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(ColorBookApp());
}

class ColorBookApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Color Book'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 50), // Add space for the arrow image
              _buildArrowImage('assets/arrow.png'),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  _buildTiltedImage('assets/image1.jpg', -10),
                  SizedBox(width: 20),
                  _buildTiltedImage('assets/image2.jpg', 10),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTiltedImage(String imagePath, double angle) {
    return Transform.rotate(
      angle: angle * 3.14 / 180,
      child: Image.asset(
        imagePath,
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildArrowImage(String imagePath) {
    return Image.asset(
      imagePath,
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    );
  }
}
```

Don't forget to add your images inside your assets folder and also play with this to get your desired design